# Object.defineProperty doesn't return Object.entries

Tags: javascript

Why both object returns in console but only the first has entries?

```js
let obj1 = {
  1: 1,
  2: 2
}

let obj2 = {}

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  Object.defineProperty(obj2, i, {
    value: i
  })
}

console.log(obj1);
console.log(Object.entries(obj1));

console.log(obj2);
console.log(Object.entries(obj2));
```

Comment: I think you may need to set `enumerable: true`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: @evolutionxbox is correct, [enumerable defaults to false](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#description)

Comment: @andreas good spot.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Second results when searching for: [javascript object.defineproperty enumerate false](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=javascript+object.defineproperty+enumerate+false+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the option `enumerable: true` so that the new properties can be enumerated.

```js
let obj1 = {
  1: 1,
  2: 2
}

let obj2 = {}

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  Object.defineProperty(obj2, i, {
    value: i,
    enumerable: true,
  })
}

console.log(obj1);
console.log(Object.entries(obj1));

console.log(obj2);
console.log(Object.entries(obj2));
```